# Combine multiple tables into one in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's say I have the following monthly tables with table names formatted such that the number after the underscore refers to the month. What I want to do is to combine these 12 tables into one without having to write 10-30 insert/union all statements

```
table_1
table_2
table_3
table_4
table_5
table_6
table_7
table_8
table_9
table_10
table_11
table_12 -- (only 12 in this instance but could be as many as 36)
```

My current approach is to first create the master table with data from `table_1`.

```
create temporary table master_table_1_12 as
select *                                       -- * to keep it simple for this example
from table_1;
```

Then use variables such that I can simply keep hitting the run button until it errors out with *"table_13 does not exist"*

```
set month_id=(select max(month_id) from master_table_1_12) + 1;
set table_name=concat('table_',$month_id);

insert into master_table_1_12 
select * 
from identifier($table_name);
```

*Note: All monthly tables have a month_id column*

Sure it saves some space on the console(compared to multiple inserts), but I still have to run it 12 times. Are **Snowflake Tasks** something I could use for this? I couldn't find a fitting example from their documentation to code that up but, if anyone had success with that or with a **Javascript based SP** for a problem like this, please enlighten.

Comment: Can you explain what the issue is that you are trying to resolve? Unioning 12 similar select statements together and inserting the result into another table is trivial and should take under a minute to write - so its not clear if there is some other issue that you are facing?

Comment: You can create a JavaScript stored procedure with a loop to do this. If you want a sample, let me know.

Comment: @GregPavlik That would be very helpful

Comment: @NickW More than an issue, I am looking for an easier/less verbose way to combine multiple tables together without using multiple inserts/union all statements. I was thinking if Tasks in Snowflake could be used for this, but couldn't find a fitting example. And I don't know Javascript for a loops based solution. It seems quite possible, there just might not be a Snowflake native solution for this

Comment: Up to you, of course, and I understand if your real world use case is more complex than the example you've given in this post, but given how trivial this is to achieve using multiple insert statements I doubt that any solution using a SP or Tasks could be described as easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a `UDF` that spits out a `create view` statement and a `stored procedure` that executes it to create a temporary view. I work with tables **following specific naming convention**, so you might have to tweak this solution a little for your use case. The separation of UDF and stored proc actually helps with that as you'd mostly need to tweak the SQL UDF. I am sharing a simplified version of what I actually have in the interest of keeping it representative of the tables I listed in my question.

**SQL UDF FOR GENERATING A CREATE VIEW STATETEMENT**

```
create or replace function sandbox.public.define_view(table_pattern varchar, start_month varchar, end_month varchar)
returns table ("" varchar) as 

$$
with cte1(month_id) as

(select start_month::int + row_number() over (order by 1) - 1 
 from table(generator(rowcount=> end_month::int - start_month::int + 1))) 
 
,cte2(month_id,statement) as

(select 0,
        concat('create or replace temporary view master_', 
                split_part(table_pattern,'.',-1), 
                start_month,
                '_', 
                end_month,
                ' as ')
 union all
 select month_id,
        concat('select * from ', 
                table_pattern,
                month_id, 
                case when month_id=end_month::int then ';' else ' union all ' end)
 from cte1)

select listagg(statement, '\n') within group (order by month_id) as create_view_statement
from cte2
$$;
```

**PROCEDURE FOR EXECUTING THE OUTPUT OF THE UDF ABOVE**

```
create or replace procedure sandbox.public.create_view(TABLE_PATTERN varchar, START_MONTH varchar,END_MONTH varchar)
returns varchar not null
language Javascript
execute as caller
as

$$
sql_command = 'select * from table(sandbox.public.define_view(:1, :2, :3))';
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: sql_command ,binds: [TABLE_PATTERN, START_MONTH, END_MONTH]}).execute();
stmt.next();
var ddl = stmt.getColumnValue(1);
var run=snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: ddl}).execute();
run.next();
var message=run.getColumnValue(1);
return "Temporary " + message;
$$;
```

**USAGE DEMO**

```
set table_pattern ='sandbox.public.table_';
set start_month ='1';
set end_month = '12';
set master_view='master_'||split_part($table_pattern,'.',-1)||$start_month||'_'||$end_month;

call create_view($table_pattern, $start_month, $end_month);
```

[image]

```
select top 100 *
from identifier($master_view);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a stored procedure that will insert into master_table_1_12 from selects on table_1 through table_12. Modify as required:

```
create or replace procedure FILL_MASTER_TABLE()
returns string
language javascript
as
$$
    var rows = 0;
    for (var i=1; i<=12; i++) {
        rows += insertRows(i);
    }
    return rows + " rows inserted into master_table_1_12.";

// End of main function

function insertRows(i) {

sql = 
`insert into master_table_1_12 
select * 
from table_${i};`;

return doInsert(sql);
}

function doInsert(queryString) {
    var out;
    cmd1 = {sqlText: queryString};
    stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd1);
    var rs = stmt.execute();;
    rs.next();
    return rs.getColumnValue(1);
}
$$;

call fill_master_table();
```

By the way, if you don't have any processing to do and just need to consolidate the tables, you can do something like this:

```
insert into master_table_1_12 
select * from table_1
    union all
select * from table_2
    union all
select * from table_3
    union all
select * from table_4
    union all
select * from table_5
    union all
select * from table_6
    union all
select * from table_7
    union all
select * from table_8
    union all
select * from table_9
    union all
select * from table_10
    union all
select * from table_11
    union all
select * from table_12
;
```

Comment: Thank you for this sample! Will I have to modify the (1) in `return rs.getColumnValue(1)`?

Comment: No, that just returns the # of rows inserted. Also, I updated my answer. If you're only consolidating the tables without doing any other processing, you can do the second code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not create a view on top of these 12 tables. The view will be an union of all these tables.

Based on the comments below, I further elaborated my answer. please try this approach. It will provide better performance when your table is large. Partitioning it will improve performance. This is based on real experience.

```
CREATE TABLE SALES_2000 (REGION VARCHAR, UNITS_SOLD NUMBER);
CREATE TABLE SALES_2001 (REGION VARCHAR, UNITS_SOLD NUMBER);
CREATE TABLE SALES_2002 (REGION VARCHAR, UNITS_SOLD NUMBER);
CREATE TABLE SALES_2003 (REGION VARCHAR, UNITS_SOLD NUMBER);

INSERT INTO SALES_2000 VALUES('ASIA', 25);
INSERT INTO SALES_2001 VALUES('ASIA', 50);
INSERT INTO SALES_2002 VALUES('ASIA', 55);
INSERT INTO SALES_2003 VALUES('ASIA', 65);

CREATE VIEW ALL_SALES AS
SELECT * FROM SALES_2000
UNION
SELECT * FROM SALES_2001
UNION
SELECT * FROM SALES_2002
UNION
SELECT * FROM SALES_2003;


SELECT * FROM ALL_SALES WHERE UNITS_SOLD = 25;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27042663)

Comment: I think it actually does answer the question and that is how I solved a similar problem. I had tables which are partitions of a large table. Each table contains the data for the particular year for example T1_2000, T1_2001,.... I created a view on top of these tables to combine all of them. The beauty of snowflake is that when I add the where clause with year, it exactly knows which year partition it needs to go.

Comment: Your answer is ok in general, however, OP clearly stated _What I want to do is to combine these 12 tables into one without having to write 10-30 insert/union all statements_

Comment: You don't need to insert. You already have those tables populated(smaller ones). When you create the view on top of the smaller partitioned table, snowflake metadata cache keeps track of the min/max of each of the tables. Hence when you do a select on the view, it directly goes to the table where the data is. I have elaborated the answer to explain this. I know I should have explained it better. There is no reason for not using UNION. Infact in snowflake, for a large table if you break up like this, it gives better performance

Comment: @RajibDeb Sorry if the intent of my question is misunderstood. I am looking for a solution/alternative other than what I already know (union all /multiple inserts). Something that requires significantly less human input instead of manually specifying table names every time I need to combine tables. I could use a CTE or a view or a temporary table using union all or inserts, but I'll still have to type in table_1 through table_N, that's what I am trying to find a solution for. A solution that capitalizes the pattern in how tables are named.

Comment: Hi Mithrandir, I actually had a similar use case like you. I understand that you do not know how many number of tables will you have but is there an upper limit that you know, for example will there be a need to create more than 36 tables. If not you can create a view with all the 36 tables. Creating another table and inserting all the rows of the smaller table again will have additional cost. It will cost you storage and additional compute. Also when you query the big table and do not order the inserts , partition pruning will not happen efficiently